Mhtml file editing
I would edit an MHT/MHTML file modifying text to its body.
I have read this question but I cannot find the way to unpack to HTML. I'm trying to do it through Chrome, but it seems able only to save in HTML, and I cannot see the way to convert and edit one format to the other.
Can you explain the correct procedure?

What are you going to do with this file?  An MHTML file is intended to be a snapshot of a web page (and its resources), not to be edited.  You can certainly expand the MHTML, make your changes, and gather it up into an MHTML again.  What language will you be using to do this?

It is meant to be outside a programming language, as I understand the quoted question it may be done through a browser, but I don't see how (in Chrome). Can you give me a hint?

There are Chrome extensions that let you save a page as a, MHTML, but you can't edit a web page in a browser.

So what was said in the quoted question was wrong? Indeed that sounded strange to me, all l had found was Developer tools in Chrome menu, and it didn't seem to consent editing the HTML part. However many users in that old thread look pretty sure it is posible to do it. What do you think?

Perhaps you should tell us what you're actually trying to DO.  MHTML files aren't really very useful, which is why you don't find tools.

Yes, I didn't find anything useful, except an online service to edit MHTML, but the result was tragic: all the original layout is lost. What I try to do is the same thing the author of the cited question wished: I need to modify text in the archive HTML body part. Basing on that question it seems possible to use IE or Chrome to unpack the archive file, but I've noticed they allow to save only in the current file format, not from one type to the other. I hope there is a way to do that

With IE (Edge) developer tools I'm able to edit the MHTML, and the browser shows the page with the modified layout (text) in real time. Unfortunately it doesn't permit to save it.

I consider MHTML useful instead. I'm trying to exploit it to create a sort of local 'web book' available on my mobile device via browser. There are however wrong parts, that's why I'm trying to change the pages content. After all, they may be considered useful as much as PDF, and PDF have tons of tools to edit, convert and so on
